# Proving divergence of recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ with $0<\alpha<\beta<\gamma$, define a sequence by $a_1 = \gamma$ and $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}^2+\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$$
I am fairly sure that this sequence diverges to $+\infty$, but how can I prove it? I thought it might be something like showing by induction that $a_n > n$ for all $n$, but that turns out to be not necessarily true (e.g. for $n=1$). And $a_n \geq n-1$ is true for $n=1$ but the inductive step doesn't work out. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that $a_{n+1} - a_n \ge \delta$ where $\delta > 0$ is a constant you construct.

You can start by noting $a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{(a_n-\alpha)(a_n-\beta)}{\alpha + \beta}$. Using induction, you should be able to easily show that $a_n$ is an increasing sequence. From there, you can figure out the $\delta$ I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Show that  $a_n \geq \gamma$ by induction.
2. Show that  $a_{n+1} - \alpha \geq k^n (a_1 - \alpha) $ for some $ k > 1$.

> 1. $\alpha_{n+1} \geq \gamma \Leftarrow \alpha_n^2 > \gamma^2 \geq \gamma\alpha + \gamma \beta - \alpha \beta  \Leftarrow (\gamma - \beta)(\gamma - \alpha) \geq 0. $

$ $

> 2. $ a_{n+1} - \alpha = (\alpha_n -\alpha) \frac{ \alpha_n + \alpha } { \beta + \alpha}$. Let $k = \frac{ \gamma + \alpha } { \beta + \alpha} > 1$.

---

Note: The condition can be weakened to $a_ 1 > \beta$, since we can then find a $\gamma$ in between them.
Conversely, if $a_1 = \beta$, then $a_i = \beta$.

Comment: I think you meant an inequality in your second point.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo. Note that I leave the hidden text up for people to look at, even if the proof is obvious once you start on it (since I don't have much faith in humanity)

Comment: Ah, learned from you about the hovering effects. Thank you!